# intellij gives error of non-whitelisted class with app engine using java 8

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

AFAIK App Engine supports all standard java libraries when project uses java 8. For some reason Intellij show this as an error. I can run local development server and deploy this project to app engine and it works ok.

[image]

I think I could just disable the check for forbidden code in App Engine but is there something else that would actually be forbidden with java 8 also. 
[image]

Is this issue with gcloud plugin or intellij...?

Edit:
Added project structure 
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/pull/1375

Comment: what runtime do you have configured in your `appengine-web.xml`? Is it `<runtime>java8</runtime>`? If not, could you try changing to that.

Comment: it is java 8. java 8 features work well when app is deployed or run as local development server.

Comment: interesting. could you possibly show a screenshot of (or type in) your facet setup? File -> Project Structure -> Facets, and also File -> Project Structure -> Modules ?

Comment: In particular, I'm wondering if the code that is giving you that inspection is part of the module that has the App Engine standard support / facet (and the appengine-web.xml with `<runtime>java8</runtime>`

Comment: BTW what version of Google Cloud Tools for IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: IntelliJ google Cloud Tools Version: 18.5.1

Comment: @eshaul I'm not sure if I can share the name of the project I am working on so I hid the project name from screenshot. I edited the original post and added screenshot.

Comment: Are you using Gradle by any chance? If so, its possible that you are running into something similar to this open issue (which will likely be fixed in the next release): https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues/2162. The workaround is described there (basically to add the appengine standard facet manually to the "other" module (the one _without_ the "_main" suffix).

Comment: If my previous comment doesn't help, you can disable the inspection for now while we figure out whats going on without worrying about it as it will not affect local run or deploy.

Comment: Since you can confirm the application is working both locally and on GAE, and also that you are using the newest version of the Google Cloud Tools plugin, we can continue working on the IntelliJ side. You can always try and import the project again. It would also be interesting if you can confirm whether you are using Gradle or Maven on your project.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8#enhancements_and_upgrades_in_the_java_8_runtime) The App Engine Java 8 runtime supports the standard public Java library, so there shouldn't be any limitations.

Ther has been an [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/pull/1375) (@CrazyCoder's comment) opened in `google-cloud-intellij` library which has been resolved in the latest version.

Comment: I should have latest of goolge-cloud-intellij. And the the app works ok on local deployment and also when deployed to GAE. So Java8 is used and it works. 

That issue has been fixed over a year ago and for sure I don't have that old components on my tool chain.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.2 build on July 2018 solved the issue